Accidentally enabled multi-cursor mode for middle mouse button in VScode
I was just typing stuff in VScode when i hit an error and started pressing random buttons, I guess that's what changed the middle mouse button (scroll wheel button) to go from auto-scrolling to doing multi-cursor text selecting.
This is what the middle mouse button is doing now. This is just very annoying and I am used to auto scrolling when i click on the middle mouse button.
I tried googling, going through many stackoverflow threads and even used ChatGPT but nothing worked for me.
P.s: This is my one of the first times asking a question here, so the format may be wrong. Sorry for that in advance.

Are you clicking and holding the middle mouse button down? That seems to be the default behavior if so - it will start highlighting using multi-cursor.

Do you have a plugin installed that does this?

@TimothyG. yep. i see, but earlier it worked as an autoscroll button

@AndyRay it was the default for me

It doesn't look like this behavior has ever existed in VSCode? Either way I don't think this question is appropriate for Stackoverflow, because there's likely not a way to help you without extensive comment back and forth. There's not enough information here to go on. I would do more research into middle click settings, look through your settings, plugins, and keyboard settings, middle click behavior for your OS/Terminal, and add more detail or open a new question if you have something more specific/actionable. My only guess is you installed the auto hotkey script on Windows & forgot about it.

@AndyRay Thank you for this question's link. I tried my best to find it but was unable to. Thanks!
I touched VScode after a long time so maybe, yes I couldve downloaded the app and have forgot about it
